# subquery inside WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some trouble inserting subquery inside WHERE statement. Code that I have so far is :

```
    select * from (
    SELECT 'P_' dmnsn  AS partition_name,
    decode(dmnsn,'PROMO','CMBD_PROMO',dmnsn_code) AS high_value,
    dmnsn AS part_pre
    FROM
       (select to_char(to_clob(COLUMN_VALUE)) as dmnsn
    from XMLTABLE(to_clob('"CLSTR","CUSTOMER","CALENDAR","TYPE",
    "PROMO","PRODUCT","PRODUCTION","STORE","WAREHOUSE","SALES","PRICE"')))
    ) 
    where ( select count(*) 'TEST_' || substr( partition_name,3) || '_VIEW' ) > 0
```

Obviously it doesn't work. ( I've just put it here to give you a glimps of what I'm trying to do)
All the views from XMLTABLE actually exist and look like this "TEST_CLSTR_VIEW".
What I'm aiming for is selecting from XMLTABLE only those values that create a view which is not empty ( contains some records )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have   several  problem in your query

1 - the use on var of database object as table or columns name is noit allowed  in SQL .. so you should build your query using another tecnique eg: building dinamically server side  the  string for your query avoinding var

2 - you missed  the FROM clause in you subselect .

3 -  the 'P_'   dmnsn   AS partition_name,  is sintactically wrong

```
select * from (
    SELECT 'P_'   dmnsn  AS partition_name,
    decode(dmnsn,'PROMO','CMBD_PROMO',dmnsn_code) AS high_value,
    dmnsn AS part_pre
    FROM
       (select to_char(to_clob(COLUMN_VALUE)) as dmnsn
    from XMLTABLE(to_clob('"CLSTR","CUSTOMER","CALENDAR","TYPE",
    "PROMO","PRODUCT","PRODUCTION","STORE","WAREHOUSE","SALES","PRICE"')))
    ) 
    where ( select count(*) FROM  YOUR_VIEW ) > 0
```

Comment: There are many issues.. `'P_' dmnsn  AS partition_name` here also it will throw error. Also if you look he is trying to execute dynamic sql, trying to use column in subquery in where clause dynamically. Here `select count(*) 'TEST_' || substr( partition_name,3) || '_VIEW' )`  in this statement `partition_name` is returned from the subquery. Your answer doesnot satisfy that

Comment: @XING  correct  .. i have looked  only at what i think are the most relevant.   For the dinamic query the OP must buil the string server side because the sue of string in the way in the question don' return a valid result

Comment: Ad. 3  should of course be SELECT 'P_'  ||  dmnsn  AS partition_name'

Comment: OK  .. but this is the minor  problem .. the use of string  concat for buil dinamic sql diectly  in a query  is not allowed  .. you must work server  side (or externally) for this ..

Comment: But the whole query without WHERE clause works just fine in SQL Developer, so what is wrong?

Comment: then if they work just add  the FROM keyword in where subselect and let me know (could be that sqldeveloper perform the correct string substitution where needed)

Comment: I've added FROM and I get "ORA-00936: missing expression" Error

Comment: then  .. try using the explicit view name instead of the string concatenated .. and let me know  ..

Comment: as it was intended to demonstrate  .. the use of string concat for build dinamic query is not allowed  so you must resolve query string externally ..